# "jtable" automatically RowSelection

Tags: java, mysql, swing

I have 2 `JTable`s. What I want is that when I select a row in `table1`, if the last value and the first value in `table2` are equal, then the row containing the value in `table2` will be selected automatically.

I've tried this code but it doesn't work. It always selects the last row.

Any help plz !

```java
int indice = table_1.getSelectedRow();
for (int i = 0; i < table_2.getRowCount(); i++) {
    if (table_2.getModel().getValueAt(i, 0) == table_1.getModel().getValueAt(indice , 5)) {
        table_2.getSelectionModel().setSelectionInterval(i, 0);
        //table_2.setRowSelectionInterval(i, i);
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you read the _javadoc_ for method [`setSelectionInterval`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/ListSelectionModel.html#setSelectionInterval-int-int-) ? If you want to select only one row, then you should use `setSelectionInterval(i, i)` Why is that commented in the code you wrote?

Comment: i was just trying the method in the comment and i forgot to remove it , i ve tried `setSelectionInterval(i, i)` but it doesn t work

Comment: 1) Don't use "==" for object comparison. Instead, use the `equals(...)` method. 2) If the last row is always selected then that means the last row meets your criteria. Post a proper [mre] demonstrating the problem. So add hard coded data to the model and get the code working. Once that works, then you worry about getting data dynamically from the database.

Comment: @camickr Thank you very much, it works now the mistake was in "==".